# Mounted Windows partition shows as empty

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, filesystem

I'm trying to access Windows files from Ubuntu. I mounted the Windows partition in read-only to `/media/windows`, but when I open the folder, it's empty. The Windows partition is displayed as `723 GB volume`, but the properties window shows it has 67 GB of free space.

The command I used to mount was `mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4 /media/windows`.

Output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="0CCEE142CEE12524" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="3072e097-bb5b-41d5-b5ee-e801527cb141"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="20E3-F007" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="47deba7d-da92-401a-9fb7-d7bb01ac2425"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2C1CF5D91CF59DD0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="820d4aff-a44b-4341-aa3b-4be46fed9c00"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="SAMSUNG_REC2" UUID="7C801A62801A2366" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b7453122-2976-4042-998e-c82abc9e79a9"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="SAMSUNG_REC" UUID="FCE9-01ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="93c03d23-427a-4089-4173-636c65706975"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="145A-3702" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="42637dc3-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="4e780686-2d33-43ea-968e-ce75355669bd"
```

My laptop model and make is a Samsung 300e, if that helps.

From `sudo fdisk -l |grep sd`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047    1024000   500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1026048    1640447     614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1640448    1902591     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1902592 1413550080 1411647489 673.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1413552128 1414471679     919552   449M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  1414471681 1463050240   48578560  23.2G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1463050241 1465147392    2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15510536192 bytes, 30294016 sectors
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30294015 30291968 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Do you have an error message when mounting ? Are you on a laptop using the hibernate feature ? Please post you /etc/fstab and the output of blkid

Comment: I mean sudo blkid ;)

Comment: Here's my situation:
There's a corrupt file that's not allowing windows 8 on my laptop to boot. I had hybrid sleep enabled, which meant that windows is still technically hibernating right now. I can't access windows to disable it. So, I'm trying to recover some files thru ubuntu. I get no error message on mounting. Posting those two outputs you asked for in a sec @SimonVanMachin

Comment: Trying to run /etc/fstab resulted in a 'permission denied' error.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l | grep sd`
sda4 does not sound correct

Comment: sudo cat /etc/fstab  -- but it will not be needed, hibernating Windows is a well known issue, if you can't boot in Windows at all, try the option "remove_hiberfile" when mounting BUT you'll end up loosing unsaved data

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/798765

Comment: @rtaft woopsie, right, maybe try to take a look at sda5 Sentricast ?(but still, if it's from an hibernating Windows, troubles you'll have;)

Comment: i'm ok with losing unsaved data, i just need a few files moved to this new laptop. thanks.

Comment: Simon's link suggests using ntfsfix, have you tried that?

Comment: yes, it returns an error related to the fact that Windows is still 'hibernating'. i'm thinking of resorting to just using the remove_hiberfile command, because nothing i need from the laptop has been opened recently, i.e i could remove the hiberfile and get everything how i'd want it.